# Is OAuth preferred for mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I have been trying to understand when to use OAuth vs SAML.  Several sites, including this one -- https://dzone.com/articles/saml-versus-oauth-which-one, say when a mobile device is involved, OAuth 2 is preferred ("If your usecase involves mobile devices, then OAuth2 with some form of Bearer Tokens is appropriate").  But from what I am reading about SAML and OAuth, they accomplish two different things.  SAML is used for single sign-on while OAuth is used for accessing specific resources (as opposed to creating a user session in another system).  So I'm not clear on why the device the end user is using should affect the decision of when each protocol is used.  Do I have this right?

Answer (score 1):

For SSO, use OpenID Connect which sits on top of OAuth.

Using that gives you the full range.

This is better than SAML because:

- SAML requires greater cryptographic functionality
- SAML requires browser redirects (not suitable for mobile applications)
- OIDC uses REST - much simpler
- API calls require OAuth token. Won't work with SAML token.

Comment: You mention, "SAML requires greater cryptographic functionality" but isn't that a good thing?  I mean increased security and all?

Comment: Yes but requires libraries etc. There aren't many SAML stacks for mobile.